# How can I bind two IO () monads without executing them?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

In the below code, I am using `>>` to concatenate IO actions together. But AFAIU, `m1>>m2` gets de-sugared to `m1>>=(\_.m2)` and thus it is executing the first IO action right when it is binding. I want all printing to happen in the main, i.e. print statements should not get interleaved with the input statements ("Enter Code"). Since `do` doesn't allow me to return any other monad than IO like `[IO ()]`. How can I have the desired printing effect?

```
f :: [Int] -> IO ()
f inventory = do
        putStrLn "Enter Code\n"
        x <- getLine
        let idx = nameToIndex x 
        putStrLn "Quantity\n"
        y <- getLine
        putStrLn "More?\n"
        c <- getChar
        let q = (read y :: Int)
        let curM = if inventory !! idx >= q then (putStrLn "sdaf\n") else (putStrLn "Overflow!\n")  
        if c == 'Y' then curM>>(f (update inventory idx)) else curM

main = f [1, 2]
```

Comment: No `>>` will not execute the first IO immediately, since an `IO` does *not* perform IO, it more or less describes *how to modify* the state of a machine, it is simply a binding of two `IO`s. In fact in Haskell nothing gets executed unless really necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem, but I think it goes like this: you'd like to do some interactions with the user, storing up information about the interaction, then display all the information at once at the end of the entire interaction.

Here's a very simplified version of your code, that skips all the business logic and just keeps asking the user if they want to continue.

```
prompt = do
    putStrLn "Continue?"
    s <- getLine
    case s of
        "y" -> putStrLn "Okay, let's continue." >> prompt
        _ -> return ()

main = prompt
```

I *think* the effect you're asking for is to delay the display of "Okay, let's continue." until the user has stopped hitting "y". That's no problem. There's lots of ways you can do this. The most flexible is to have `prompt` return the action it wants to be executed after it completes:

```
prompt = do
    putStrLn "Continue?"
    s <- getLine
    case s of
        "y" -> do
            act <- prompt
            return (putStrLn "Okay, let's continue." >> act)
        _ -> return (return ())

main = do
    act <- prompt
    act
```

(There are combinators that can make this code more compact, as well.) But I don't like this design; it makes it difficult to introspect on the result of `prompt`. A more specialized but also more maintainable approach is to return some data describing the interaction, which the caller can then turn into an `IO` action summarizing things. In this case, a list of strings seems like a suitable description.

```
prompt = do
    putStrLn "Continue?"
    s <- getLine
    case s of
        "y" -> do
            results <- prompt
            return ("Okay, let's continue." : results)
        _ -> return []

main = do
    results <- prompt
    mapM_ putStrLn results
```

Hopefully this explanation is clear enough that you can combine this idea with your more complicated business logic.